# Why is the walk stream of fs-extra not working with jasmine

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I don't know why this is not working. I want to use the walk function/stream of the great [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) module.

At all I am not able to call that stream so that it is working together with jasmine.

I already tried the beforeEach or beforeAll like it is described in [the documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support).

My version of jasmine is 2.3.2

I guess that the events are not called. Because of that everything inside the stream is not working inside the jasmine enviroment.

I made a small test example:

```
fs = require("fs-extra");
console.log("console log output");
fs.walk(__dirname)
.on("data", function (item) {
  console.log (item.path);
})
```

Calling that part via `node spec/testSpec.js` everything works fine. By using `jasmine` the output is just *console log output*

So why are that streams not working? Is there a solution? Or do I need to use another tool for testing code with streams?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: You have to add callback to the function cos fs.walk is async, the tests has to wait for it to finish.